# Unexpected behaviour from Readline's bind command

Tags: bash, readline

I hadn’t yet researched whether or not bracketed paste mode is supported by the version of Bash/Readline on my Ubuntu 16.04 system (it isn’t) and out of curiosity, I ran the following command presented in this [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/738649/93375).

```
bind 'set-enable-bracketed-paste off'
```

If the `set-enable-bracketed-paste` setting didn’t exist, I’d expect `bind` to either complain about bad syntax or to do nothing. Instead, it unbound the lower case `p`, i.e., the character disappears into a black hole when typed.

It seems that this usage of the `bind` command unbinds the character that immediately follows the last hyphen before the first space character (if there’s any space in the string).  E.g., I ran the following commands:

This results in the `r` character being unbound:

```
bind '__-r anymorecharacters'
```

This unbinds the character, `2`:

```
bind 'xxxx-1-2xxx'
```

The characters can still be entered by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
before entering the character, thus allowing them to be re-bound:

```
bind 'r: self-insert'
bind '2: self-insert'
```

To me, this is unexpected and surprising behaviour and I’d consider it to be a bug. However, I’m not very familiar with Readline so I thought I’d ask here to check if there’s a reasonable explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383670/ .

Comment: And https://superuser.com/questions/726086/ on SuperUser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Readline's configuration file parser has some poor error checking.

`set-enable-bracketed-paste` is parsed in the way that, say, `control-DEL` or `meta-q` would be parsed.  Readline takes the final minus-delimited part and tries to understand it as a key name, and takes the rest and tries to understand it as a sequences of modifiers.

[The code that recognizes the key](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline/blob/9e182c9a057c8f3eea14bf5dc13f047fbb260abd/bind.c#L1717) blithely falls back to just looking at the first character if no name in its table of key names matches.  So `paste` is taken to denote the `p` key.

[The code that looks for modifiers](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline/blob/9e182c9a057c8f3eea14bf5dc13f047fbb260abd/bind.c#L1381) does not care if there are other non-modifier things in the string and does not expect modifiers to be minus-terminated.  So `set-enable-bracketed-` is simply treated as no modifiers.

This does not "unbind the `p` key".  It *re-*binds the `p` key to the function named "`off`".  [The code that does that](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline/blob/9e182c9a057c8f3eea14bf5dc13f047fbb260abd/bind.c#L1412) does not raise an error if no function named "`off`" can be found in the function table.  [The default function table](https://github.com/JuliaLang/readline/blob/9e182c9a057c8f3eea14bf5dc13f047fbb260abd/funmap.c#L61) has no such function.

Comment: Many thanks for this thoroughly well-reseached answer which does a great job of explaining this behaviour.