# bash throws "set-ena" when I press/write b in the terminal

Tags: bash, zsh, bashrc, set

I have an extremely weird error:
when I write the letter *b* in my terminal, bash immediately starts to write/throw endless stream of "set-enaset-enaset-enaset-enaset-enaset-ena..." until I force it to stop, by Ctrl-C, or exiting bash. I have removed my .bashrc and replaced it with a default one, but it didn't help. I have also purged bash, and reinstalled it, and also it did not help. Interestingly, when I use my zsh in the same terminal, it works without this error. When I use bash not in the terminal programme, but simply in ubuntu text-mode (console) the error also happens.

When I copy-paste the letter *b* it also happens. I should note, that it's not required to write *b* and press enter, the stream of "set-enaset-ena..." starts even before I am able to press *enter*.

**EDIT:** I disovered that when I enter the command: *set -o vi* manually then it's not broken anymore (until I enter *set -o emacs*. However, when I tried to put *set -o vi* into my .bashrc, then it didn't work, and actually I had to switch to emacs mode this time for it to work. 
Strangely, changing the mode manually, from whatever it was before to something else fixes this weird problem

Comment: My crystal ball says the "ena" is the beginning of "enable". Remember that there's also `.profile` which is read on startup. What happens if you run `bash --noprofile --norc` from zsh?

Comment: It also gives the same error. However I discovered something else (see EDIT)

Comment: Maybe a ~/.inputrc (or /etc/inputrc) file has something in it that might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [mtklr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/123511/mtklr) for help!! I checked my /etc/inputrc file and found out that I had a line that said:
`bind 'set enable-bracketed-paste on'` which caused the error. I assume the `b` from `bind` caused the trouble. I guess the proper script would not include the `bind` command. Thanks everyone for help!