# Using bind breaks shell

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, readline, windows-subsystem-for-linux

*(WSL with Ubuntu 18.04)*

I have some configuration settings that I have used before and that can be seen recommended in various places across the internet (not to mention on SO). I hav placed them in a `.inputrc` file in my home location.

```bsh
$include /etc/inputrc

# better tab completion
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
bind "set completion-ignore-case on"

# disable bell
bind "set bell-style none"

# make tab completion treat links as directories
# i.e. adds trailing slash when <tab>-ing
set mark-symlinked-directories on
```

I'm not clear on why `bind` is used or not used for these. Internet says `bind` is used for the `readline` library. Internet also says `.inputrc` is for the `readline`. So they should work together, right?

But when I use these crazy things start to happen in buy terminal (WSL).

In one case (disabling the bell) anytime I type more than N letters at the prompt, bash starts spitting out `set` over and over without end.

[image: shell printing set over and over]

In another case (the tab completion) it spits out "set completion-ignore-case on" after every character I type.

[image: shell printing configuration setting after a character]

The odd behaviour stops if I remove the `bind` and quotes, so I do not need to know *how* to stop this behaviour. I would like to understand *why* this happens. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Wy do you have `bind` there at all? It looks like a series of `set` commands just like the very last line.

Comment: @Kusalananda copy-pasta from SO. Honestly I do not know bash or readline very well. `bind` is a readline command and `inputrc` is a readline config file, so why would it *not* be used there?

Comment: Ah reading new text seems to provide some clarity "`bind`is a *bash* builtin for readline" (emphasis mine). I see the problem now, d'oh!

Comment: This will be https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477511/5132 again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment from @Kusalanada the light dawned with me that `bind`is the *bash* builtin for `readline`. As `.inputrc` is `readline` config, it doesn't need or know about bash builtins.

This is why `bind` was needed in, say, `.bashrc`, but not in `.inputrc`.